# loopback cloudant connector connection pooling

Tags: connection-pooling, loopbackjs, cloudant

I am using loopback's Cloudant connector through my Node.js code. https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Cloudant+connector

Do i need to take care of connection pooling (programatically or through configurations) ? Or is it being taken care by default ?

Can anybody please direct me to specific documentation which talks about this so that i can take an informed design decision.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the loopback connnector (https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-cloudant) uses the cloundant library (https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant) which uses the nano library (https://github.com/dscape/nano). The nano library talks about pooling as follows:

***pool size and open sockets***

*a very important configuration parameter if you have a high traffic website and are using nano is setting up the pool.size. by default, the node.js http global agent (client) has a certain size of active connections that can run simultaneously, while others are kept in a queue. pooling can be disabled by setting the agent property in requestDefaults to false, or adjust the global pool size using:*

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 20;
```

*you can also increase the size in your calling context using requestDefaults if this is problematic. refer to the request documentation and examples for further clarification.*

*...*

The nodejs documentation says the default is **infinity**:

From https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets:

***agent.maxSockets***

*By default set to Infinity. Determines how many concurrent sockets the agent can have open per origin. Origin is either a 'host:port' or 'host:port:localAddress' combination.*

If I am following all this correctly, it looks like by default connection pooling should be taken care of. In extremely high load scenarios you may need to turn it down.